# Array in Ruby on rails, undefined method `minimum'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
@click = Missing.select{|d| d.click < 10000}

find = @click.minimum(:id)
@data = Missing.where(id: find)
dataSize = @data.size
@renderData = @data[dataSize - 1]
render :json => @renderData
```

Errors:

```
undefined method `minimum' for #<Array:0x00000004acd678>

Error code : find = @click.minimum(:id)
```

I have no idea why it is wrong.

`render :json = @click` is working.
 `find = Missing.minimum(:id)` is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@click` is an array, not an association.

Why don't you use activerecord query to get your `find`?

```
find = Missing.where('click < 10000').minimum(:id)
```

Comment: You should then vote and choose the answer. That's how it works here.

Comment: oh i didnt know that.. sorry i did vote every answer but the number isn't raised T.T

Answer (score 1):

`@click = Missing.select{|d| d.click < 10000}` is returning an array of active record instances. This is why `minimum` can not be called against an `array`.

If you want the first record in the `@click` set then use `@click.first.id`. If you want the smallest (min) id then use `@click.map(&:id).min`. Looking at your code i'm not sure what you are trying to achieve?

On a side note, i'd avoid calling `Missing.select{|d| d.click < 10000}` because that is doing a full table scan on your `Missing` model's table. As [Ruby Racer says, better to query with active record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43129562/4852737).